# How to fix the error, "Invalid expression term 'else'"?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with some C# code that I made at school when I was bored :)
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string RealUsername = "root";
            string RealPassword = "passwd";
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string Username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string Password = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Username == RealUsername) ;
            {
                if (Password == RealPassword);
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Correct Login");
                }
                else;
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Login");
                }
            }
            else;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Login");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that i keep getting the error:

```
Invalid expression term 'else'
```

If anyone could fix this up, that would be great :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that programming questions are off-topic here. You can ask questions like this on [so], but make sure to read through their help center first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is valid C# code:

```
if (Password == RealPassword) ;
```

This is valid syntax for a single-line `if`. The single expression inside the `if` just happens to be an empty expression (i.e. `;`).

The following is also valid C# code:

```
{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct Login");
}
```

The brackets form a section of grouped code. The brackets themselves do nothing in this case, but this is a possible way to organize your code into visual collapsible groups. (If you're using Visual Studio, though, the recommended way is to use `#region XXX` and `#endregion`.)

The following, however, is **not** valid C# code:

```
else ;
```

Because the previous `if` was terminated by the empty expression and was then followed by other code, this `else` is left orphaned. That is an error, which causes your program not to compile.

To get your desired result, remove the semicolons from after your `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: This is a better answer to understand what actually is wrong instead of a simple "Here is the fix" kind of answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am versed in Java, C, C++ sytax practices. If C# is similar then you are not understanding the usage of semicolon: `;`

Here is what your code should be; only looking at your misuse of semicolons.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string RealUsername = "root";
            string RealPassword = "passwd";
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string Username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string Password = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Username == RealUsername)
            {
                if (Password == RealPassword)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("Correct Login");
                }
                else
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Login");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Login");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements have a semicolon at the end, which finishes the statement:

`if (Username == RealUsername) ;`

Remove it and works. Same for the `else;`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon at the end of "else"

Corrected Code given below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string RealUsername = "root";
        string RealPassword = "passwd";
        Console.Write("Username: ");
        string Username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string Password = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Username == RealUsername)
        {
            if (Password == RealPassword)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Correct Login");
            }
            else
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Login");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Login");
        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove semicolons from conditions, as in c# or most of the programming languages semicolon (';') tells the compiler to end the statement and execute it. So if you put ';' after condition, compiler will execute it but will not understand what to do after success/failure of that condition. So makers of compiler put certain conditions or exception that thrown at compile time to let the user know if there is something wrong with the code.

```
                if (Password == RealPassword) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Correct Login");
                }
                else 
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Login");
                }
```